# Properties of Riemann integral $\left| \int_b^{a}f\right| \lt \int_b^{a}|f|$？

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

$$f(x) \lt |f(x)|\implies\int_b^{a}f \lt \int_b^{a}|f|,$$

$$-f(x) \lt |f(x)|\implies-\int_b^{a}f \lt \int_b^{a}|f|.$$

Hence ,
$$-\int_b^{a}|f| \lt \int_b^{a}f \lt \int_b^{a}|f|.$$

Therefore 
$$\left| \int_b^{a}f\right| \lt \int_b^{a}|f|.$$

This inequality is correct?
My book has a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct. Why do you think it is not? It's important to tell us what you're doubting so that we can explain.

The proof is correct as well.

Comment: No I will correct this with my prof. But 2 inequality not sure of them -sorry my language not good-

Comment: @user8664468 You don't need to say sorry about your English. Your proof is correct!